# Microsoft.WebApplication.Targets not found error while running nuget pack A.csproj from command line, but works in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

I am trying to run the command `nuget pack project.csproj` from the command line but get the following error:

> ProgamFiles (x86)\MSBuild...\Microsoft.WebApplication.Targets was not found

this pops up on the command line, even though the compiler works perfectly on VS2013 (same install).

Since the questions I've run into so far have to do with VS not working, I wrote this question.